# Replace Method in Class with Reference to Itself

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assuming I can't modify or directly import a class (defined in module A) in a different module (B) say:

Part of module A:

```
class Tester(ParentHere):

   def run():
      print 100
      super(Tester, self).run()
```

How do I overwrite the `run()` method if I have access to the object?

For example I have,

Part of module B:

```
tester = factory.GetTester()
tester.run = some_method_here
```

How do I define `some_method_here` here to still call the parent class with `super(Tester, self).run()` if I can't directly import the `Tester` class or modify its original definition in module A?

For example:

```
def some_method_here():
    print '200 instead but do not print 100'
    super(Tester, self).run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still get a reference to `Tester` using the `__class__` attribute of the instance. So inside, `some_method_here`, you could call `super(self.__class__, self).run()` and then run your own code. That way, whenever `run` is called on that specific object, it'll still execute all the code in `Tester.run` plus anything you add in your function.

```
def some_method_here(self):
    # execute all your code ...
    print '200 instead but do not print 100'
    super(self.__class__, self).run()
```

In your example though, when it calls `super`, it will still print `100` since you are executing `Tester.run` after your own code.

i.e. You'll see

```
200 instead but do not print 100
100
```

in the log.

If you only wanted it to print the 200 line (i.e. not execute the code in `Tester.run`), don't call `super` in the first place.

Also, `super` only works when calling it on classes that inherit from `object` so be mindful of that. If `Tester` doesn't inherit from object, you can't call `super` on it.

Just a side note, you can't directly assign a method using `tester.run = some_method_here` because `some_method_here` won't receive a `self` argument. You would have to do `tester.run = types.MethodType(some_method_here, tester)` using the `types` module.

Answer (score 1):

In your `some_method_here`, add a parameter `tester` that you will use in the `super()` call:

```
def some_method_here(tester):
    print '200 instead but do not print 100'
    super(type(tester), tester).run()
```

Then to get a callable with the right `tester` parameter plugged in, make a partial:

```
from functools import partial

tester = factory.GetTester()

tester_method_here = partial(some_method_here, type=tester)

tester.run = tester_method_here
```